# How to replace Tomahawk <t:saveState> and <t:dataList> tags with standard JSF tags?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, tomahawk

I found [this](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/10/effective-datatable-paging-and-sorting.html) JSF tutorial which shows how to create JSF table with pagination and sorting

```html
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk" prefix="t"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<f:view>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <title>Effective datatable paging and sorting at DAO level</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h:form id="form">

                <%-- The sortable datatable --%>
                <h:dataTable value="#{myBean.dataList}" var="item">
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:commandLink value="ID" actionListener="#{myBean.sort}">
                                <f:attribute name="sortField" value="id" />
                            </h:commandLink>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.id}" />
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:commandLink value="Name" actionListener="#{myBean.sort}">
                                <f:attribute name="sortField" value="name" />
                            </h:commandLink>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.name}" />
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:commandLink value="Value" actionListener="#{myBean.sort}">
                                <f:attribute name="sortField" value="value" />
                            </h:commandLink>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.value}" />
                    </h:column>
                </h:dataTable>

                <%-- The paging buttons --%>
                <h:commandButton value="first" action="#{myBean.pageFirst}"
                    disabled="#{myBean.firstRow == 0}" />
                <h:commandButton value="prev" action="#{myBean.pagePrevious}"
                    disabled="#{myBean.firstRow == 0}" />
                <h:commandButton value="next" action="#{myBean.pageNext}"
                    disabled="#{myBean.firstRow + myBean.rowsPerPage >= myBean.totalRows}" />
                <h:commandButton value="last" action="#{myBean.pageLast}"
                    disabled="#{myBean.firstRow + myBean.rowsPerPage >= myBean.totalRows}" />
                <h:outputText value="Page #{myBean.currentPage} / #{myBean.totalPages}" />
                <br />

                <%-- The paging links --%>
                <t:dataList value="#{myBean.pages}" var="page">
                    <h:commandLink value="#{page}" actionListener="#{myBean.page}"
                        rendered="#{page != myBean.currentPage}" />
                    <h:outputText value="<b>#{page}</b>" escape="false"
                        rendered="#{page == myBean.currentPage}" />
                </t:dataList>
                <br />

                <%-- Set rows per page --%>
                <h:outputLabel for="rowsPerPage" value="Rows per page" />
                <h:inputText id="rowsPerPage" value="#{myBean.rowsPerPage}" size="3" maxlength="3" />
                <h:commandButton value="Set" action="#{myBean.pageFirst}" />
                <h:message for="rowsPerPage" errorStyle="color: red;" />

                <%-- Cache bean with data list, paging and sorting variables for next request --%>
                <t:saveState value="#{myBean}" />
            </h:form>
        </body>
    </html>
</f:view>
```

Can this table be used without `Tomahawk` library? I want to use clean JSF as much as I can? Can this code be edited with just standard JSF tags without changing the pagination and sorting?

Best wishes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That old article is targeted on JSF 1.x and the code is intended to be used with a request scoped bean. The `<t:saveState>` makes sure that the request scoped bean is retained in the next POST request, exactly like as the new JSF 2.x view scope does (which thus didn't exist in standard JSF 1.x yet). The session scope is not an option because it would lead to unintuitive behaviour and "wtf?" situations when the enduser opens the very same page in multiple browser windows/tabs and thus every request based action would affect the behavior of the same page in the other window/tab as well when the enduser switches between them and invokes request based actions on them.

For JSF 2.x, the `<t:saveState>` can be replaced by just putting the bean in the view scope instead of the request scope by marking it `@ViewScoped`.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean {
    // ...
}
```

Also please note that the article is using the old JSP view technology. This has been succeeded by Facelets since JSF 2.0. You'd like also want to replace JSP by Facelets. Remove those JSP taglibs by the usual XML namespace declarations in the top level tag (the `<html>` tag) and rename the file from `.jsp` to `.xhtml`. This way you'll be able to replace `<t:dataList>` by `<ui:repeat>` which does not exist in JSP.

```html
<ui:repeat value="#{myBean.pages}" var="page">
    ...
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: Ok, I understand and I will use only @ViewScoped in the future. I will be more specific: How I can replace this code http://pastebin.com/ExLrdX3u with h library tags - I want to replace the t library tag with h library without changing the final result.

Comment: Can I replace <t:saveState value="#{SessionsController}" /> with <h:commandButton value="#{SessionsController}" /> or I must use other tag?

Comment: No, just remove it and use `@ViewScoped`, as answered. The command button does something entirely different, namely submitting the form and invoking a backing bean action method.

Comment: This is the edited code: http://pastebin.com/emF5dRry. I hope it's going to work. Thank you!

Comment: @BalusC I also followed your method but what about managedProperty's scope like `#{daoFactoryMain}` ? Before it was request scope now I created custom view scope for that spring bean, the problem is I don't know how to handle hibernate session now. Before as it was request scope every time it was created fresh then closed but now every get request creates new daoFactory and with the known problem of ViewScope (memory leak) they stay opened in the memory. Could you give a hint about it please? I really am stuck.